# My blog which gets 300+ daily impressions has stopped appearing on the 1st page of Google

Tags: seo, google

I have a blog regarding Placement papers from December 2010. My monthly impressions are around 4000. For the last 2 days, my blog has disappeared from Google search engine result pages.  Impressions have reduced drastically.

Please check Stat reports: 
[image: Stats Reports]

My blog is still on the search engine because when I search `site: mydomain.com` on Google, I can see my all pages indexed over there…

But my pages which used to appear on the first or second pages of Google do not appear any more.

Example: If I search with query `GE round 2 code writing test` on bing.com or Yahoo search, the first link on the result page is my blog.

But if you do same on Google, my URLs do not appear even on the 1st 3 result pages. I used to get lots of visitors by these search query earlier.

Comment: I had to remove your URL as it would made this question essentially a website review which [is not considered to be an acceptable question](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/253/seo-website-reviews).

Comment: @ John Code: i didn't want website review but still there is no satisfactory answers yet. I dont agree your Comment **free labor ** are applicable for my question because i dont want any free SEO tipp or work. I just wanted some one to explain me the reason. I think this is not the proper place to ask seo related questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of reasons that your site can begin ranking poorly with Google. The first step is to find out exactly what has happened:

> 1. **Deindexed** – When your domain is completely removed from Google.
>      Also known as Banned.
> 2. **Penalized** – When your domain or page still exists but none of your
>      pages can be found through very direct search queries.  This penalty
>      can be automatic through the Google algorithm or manually applied by a
>      Google Quality Engineer.
> 3. **Sunk** – Your domain or page wasn’t Deindexed or Penalized, but the
>      traffic you were getting from Google suddenly drops dramatically. Also
>      known as Sent To Hell and Sandboxed.

From your description, it sounds like you've been Penalized. The following site has a great description of reasons that you might be penalized and what you can do about it:

- [Electron Plumber: What to do when your site drops in the Google Search results](http://electronplumber.com/what-to-do-when-your-site-drops-in-the-google-search-results/)

Comment: I was really waiting for this answer. Thanks a lot Ciaran.

Comment: Can you explain more about no 3 'sunk'. E.g. what causes this?

Comment: Even I am confused between Penalized and Sunk..

Answer (score 3):

My first tip to you would be not to share your stats to the world. You can add a printscreen to it or something like that, but don't randomly share all stats because I as a webmaster can come and steal your keywords, build another site and make it rank in Google Search better that your site.

I think what your are experiencing is a normal loss in rankings due to the Google database shift. I've looked over your site and frankly it looks a bit spammy. Try placing less ads on it and try getting more traffic rather than over-monetizing your blog.

The tips I have for you at this point, if you want to make some money online is:

1. Learn some basic SEO, and really start from the basics.
2. Get a paid and hosted domain. Really get one and make it good. (Use WordPress on it)
3. Provide some good content, 50+ blog posts and don't even start thinking about monetizing it until you have reached 20 posts on you blog.
4. Optimize traffic, build links, socialize and you will get ranking.

It's some work, but worth it in the end.

Comment: Thanx Daniel,fr your valuable comments..i agree wid ur comments about over monetizing..but not about being spammy. i just tried making it simple as it has education related content. i know seo(meta,page rank,title,tags etc,key words etc) and understand it..on this blog i have written around 72 posts.My point is what can be the reson..you have mentioned **Google database shift** then am i the only victim ?? will google start showing my pages again??

Comment: You are not the first nor will you be the last victim of the Google algo. A database shift is just a major shift of rankings caused by an event - and many times we can't know what that event is. Well, what you need to do is strip the ads from your site. I don't know what ads you have, but leave only adsense at first. Then, show more content on the homepage, useful one. When I landed there I thought I was on an adsense page. 10 posts on the homepage at lest, maybe also some navigational links, categorie. Make your site valuable to the reader. Imagine you just came from G to your site..

Comment: Yes..you are right..i have removed ads and only adsense is there on my site now. But do u think having ads is the reason why my pages are dropped ?. lots of useless stuff is still indexed and comes on the 1st page  of google... is there any chance for my blog to come back on the Google.?

Comment: The fact is you may never know the reason. But a lot of ads is many times a reason. You also have a lot of ads at the top. I would use those as navigational links. I don't want to sound too harsh, but are you using the site to make money, right? Then do a proper keyword research on it, determine what you want to rank for and make all more organized. The long category list on the right shouldn't be there for instance as long as you are not using it for navigation. That plugin you have, for facebook, cuts out of the page. Not good. Also, don't mix buttons and ads, make ads clear on the site.

Comment: I was started it to help my junior friends and later monetized it. I should have used adsesene only but i opted for some low value ads because my adsense was not working well initially. But after it started working nicelyfor me. I should have removed but i thought having those ads on my blog wouyld get some more $. You may use the word that it became my monetizing tool later. Thanks for your comment and help. I appreciate it.